# Java generics weird behaviour

Tags: java, generics

It's hard to explain in words, but Java Generics are given me an unexpected result. I expected that if I say a list is of type `? extends Object`, I could store anything in there. Therefore, if the list of of type `Wrapper<? extends Object>`, I could store any kind of Wrapper in there. And so on. That makes sense to me. But let's assume we have:

```
private static class Wrapper<T> {
    public Wrapper(T t) { /**/ }
}
```

And I want something like:

```
private static final List<Wrapper<Wrapper<? extends Object>>> ls1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Note that this gives me an error:

```
public static <T> doit(T t) {
    Wrapper<Wrapper<T>> l1 = new Wrapper<>(new Wrapper<>(t));
    ls1.add(l1); // nok
    // add (Wrapper<Wrapper<? extends java.lang.Object>>) in List
    // cannot be applied to (Wrapper<Wrapper<T>>
}
```

But if I wrap the Wrapper in a secondary Wrapper (rs), then:

```
private static class C<T> extends Wrapper<Wrapper<T>> {
    public C(T t) {
        super(new Wrapper<>(t));
    }
}

private static final List<C<? extends Object>> ls2 = new ArrayList<>();

public static <T> doit(T t) {
    ls2.add(new C<>(t)); // ok
}
```

Note that it is the same thing; this make no sense to me.

PS. In my case, I'm not making a wrapper wrapper, but a ThreadLocal of a generic class.

Comment: So what you really want is `List<Wrapper<Wrapper<Object>>>`?

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, but then I can't store a List<Wrapper<Wrapper<String>> in there. I want to be able to store any sort of Wrapper<Wrapper<String>>.

Comment: Can you change your example to something concrete, like `String` as in your comment? It's throwing me off to see a reference declaration of type `T`.

Comment: When you create `Wrapper<Wrapper<T>> l1` where are you getting this T from?

Comment: @LuanNico what you want isn't type safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

```
? extends Object ---> equals ?
```

You can do like this

```
List<Wrapper<Wrapper<?>>> ls1 = new ArrayList<>();

And

Wrapper<Wrapper<?>> l1 = new Wrapper<>(new Wrapper<>(t));
ls1.add(l1); // OK
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I would have to look into it in more detail why it does not work. Its most likely related to the generic type erasure. 
What I have is a workaround, I know this solution looses the typ for the l1 object. If this is ok for you take it.

```
Wrapper<Wrapper<? extends Object>> l1 = new Wrapper<>(new Wrapper<>(t));
ls1.add(l1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to decide what's more important, being generic over what you want to *put* into the wrapper, over or what you take *out* of the wrapper (you cannot safely both). After deciding, you will then need to choose between `extends` and `super`.

If you *just* want to store the pointer then `List<Wrapper<Wrapper>>` will suffice, but then you will need to do some casting later.

---

When you are using **`extends`** then`? extends Foo` means that any data type *returned* by the structure will a subtype of type `Foo` (or `Foo` itself).

For example if you have `void doIt1( List< ? extends Mammal> l  ){}` you could pass in `List<Human>`, `List<Primate>`, `List<Simian>` or a `List<Mammal>`.

However when using `? extends` you don't know what is safe to put in.

Consider this:

```
void addElephant( List< ? extends Mammal> l  ){
    l.add( new Elephant() ); //wrong!
}
```

This is clearly **unsafe**! I could have passed in a `List<Human>` as `l` and now my list of `Human`s has a `Elephant` in it!

On the other hand you have **`super`** where `? super Foo` means that the container can take a `Foo`.

So for `void doIt2( List< ? extends Human> l  ){}` as you could pass in `List<Human>`, `List<Primate>`, `List<Simian>`, `List<Mammal>`, or a `List<Object>`.

```
void ( List< ? super Human> l  ){
    l.add( new Human() );
}
```

And this is fine, but you cannot guarantee anything about what you will get out of the container.

```
void ( List< ? super Human> l  ){
    Human h = l.get(0); //wrong!
}
```

That is because if `l` was really a `List<Primate>` it could have a mixture of `Human`s and `Gorilla`s and there is no guarantee that the first element will be a `Human`.

For this you will get the acronym `P.E.C.S` = "[a] **P**roducer ** **E**xtends, [but a] **C**onsumer **S**upers".

If you're container is returning object to a method (eg `get`), then you are a "producing" (so use `extends`), otherwise if you are accepting elements (eg `add`) to a container, the container is "consuming" the object so use "super". (**Nb:** tricky parts to remember about PECS is that it is from the point-of-view of the container and *not* the calling code!).

If you want to **both** produce and consume you'll need to have a concrete type list `List<Primate>` where you can add `Human`s and retrieve `Primate`s.

---

**See also:**

- [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/254477)
- [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4343202/254477)

Comment: To be honest it seems that you pot a high amount of effort into this, but he simply wants to keep the type safety of l1 and your writing an essay about the method.

Comment: @mh-dev yeah, I wanted to explain what was wrong with a naive approach to his question _and_ as a reference to be able to point to for our interns and junior developers.